# Python: handle any and all postgres timeout situations

Tags: python, postgresql, networking, timeout, rds

I am struggling to find a solution to this.

We use Python to monitor our Postgres databases that are running on AWS RDS. This means we have extremely limited control over the server side.

If there is an issue, and the server fails (hardware fault, network fault, you name it) our scripts just hang for sometimes 8-10 minutes (non-SSL) and up to 15-20 minutes (SSL connections). And by the time they recover, and finally reach whatever timeout this random amount of minutes is from, the server has failed over and everything works again.

Obviously, this renders our tools useless, if we can't catch these situations.

We basically run this (pseudo-code):

```
while True:
  try:
    query("select current_user")
  except:
    page("Database X failed")
```

For the basic use cases, this works just fine. E.g. if an instance is restarted, or something of the sort, no problems.

But, if there is an actual issue, the query just hangs. For minutes and minutes.

We've tried setting the statement_timeout on the psycopg2 connection. But that is a server setting, and if the instance fails and fails over, well, there is no server. So the client ends up waiting indefinitely or until it hits one of those arbitrary timeouts.

I've looked into sockets and tested something like this:

```
  pg.connect('user', 'db-name', instanceName = 'foo')

  fd = pg.Connection.fileno()
  s = socket.socket(fileno=fd)
  print(s)
  s.settimeout(0.0000001)
  timeval = struct.pack('ll', 0, 1)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_RCVTIMEO, timeval)
  s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_SNDTIMEO, timeval)
  data = pg.query("SELECT pg_sleep(10);")
```

In dumping the socket with the print(s) statement, I can clearly see that we've got the right socket.

But the timeouts I set, do nothing whatsoever.

I've tried many values, and it just has no effect. With the above, it should raise a timeout if more than 1 microsecond has elapsed. Ignoring common sense, I checked with tcpdump and made sure that we definitely do not get a response in 1 microsecond. Yet the thing just sits there and waits for to pg_sleep(10) to complete.

Could someone shed some light on this?

It seems simple enough:

All I want is that ANY CALL made to postgres can NEVER TAKE LONGER than, say, 10 seconds. Regardless of what it is, regardless of what happens. If more than 10 seconds have elapsed, it needs to raise an exception.

From what I can see, the only way would be to use subprocess with a process-timeout. But we run threaded (we monitor hundreds of instances and spawn a persistent connection in a thread for each instance) and I've seen posts saying that this isn't reliable inside threads. It also seems silly to have each thread spawn yet another subprocess. Inception comes to mind. Where does it end?

But I digress. The question seems simple enough, yet my wall is showing clear signs of a large dent developing.

Greatly appreciate any insights

PS: Python 3.6 on Ubuntu LTS

Cheers

Stefan